# Beta app not showing up in Play Store

Tags: android, google-play

Hey so I published my app in the Beta category, (the drop-down menu says it's published) and created a Google+ Community so me and a few others can test the app. I published it yesterday around this time (24h). I heard that it only takes a few hours to get on the store. Why can't me or my testers see the app? I even tried clicking the View in Google Play Store link they give you but I get this message:

> We're sorry, the requested URL was not found on this server.

Answer (score 1):

From your google play account, you can take the url of the app and send it to the community.

Comment: from my Dev Console or Google Play customer account?

Comment: NVM I see what you mean, Thankyou.

Comment: I would add that this link is somewhat easy to figure out: play.google.com/apps/testing/full.package.name

Answer (score 1):

The link as provided by Google Play in the Developer Console did not work for me. I had to first visit http://play.google.com/apps/testing/full.package.name (as pointed out by user dominik4142) to become a beta tester. Only when I then accepted being a tester (of my own app, under my own account) did the Google Play link as provided by Google start working for me.